# What happens to the electron if the nuclues instantaneously disappears?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms, protons

Imagine a hydrogen atom alone within an empty universe. Now imagine that the proton that the electron in the our hypothetical atom is bound to instantaneously disappears. From a quantum perspective, what exactly happens to that electron? Does its probability density ripple out into the surrounding universe?

Comment: Apply the instant perturbation theory. Look, for example, how atomic ionization is calculated when the nucleus gets an instant push (see Landau-Lifshitz textbook with the A. Migdal approach).

Answer (score 1):

> Now imagine that the proton that the electron in the our hypothetical atom is bound to **instantaneously** [my emph.] disappears.

The thorny word here is **instantaneously**:  nothing can *truly* happen instantaneously (that is: event duration $\Delta t=0$) as it would violate Relativity's universal speed limit, $c$. So it's not a very interesting question because it's a purely hypothetical event.

Consider the *time dependent* Schrödinger equation (TDSE) for a hydrogen atom with a **vanishing nucleus**:

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(r,t)=\Big[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}+U(r,t)\Big]\Psi(r,t)\tag{1}$$
Where:
$$U(r,t)=-\frac{Z(t)^2e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0r}\tag{2}$$
For a normal hydrogen atom $Z(t)=1$ and so the potential function $(2)$ becomes:

$$U(r)=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0r}$$

With $U$ no longer time dependent, $(1)$ can then be solved [the usual way](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/237/hatom.php) and provides wave function solutions as per usual.

**But** in the case of a vanishing nucleus we'd have $Z(0)=1$ and $Z(+\infty)\to 0$.

The trouble is that when $U$ is time dependent, the usual and enormously simplifying 'trick' of separating the wave function into a time dependent part $T(t)$ and a spatially dependent part $\psi(r)$:

$$\Psi(r,t)=\psi(r)T(t)$$

[(The separation method for the TDSE can be found here.)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285903/how-is-the-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-solved-for-time-varying-curved-potential-barrier/285921#285921)

... is no longer possible because $(1)$ is not a linear partial differential equation anymore.

If $Z(t)$ was known then possibly numerical methods could be used to find the electron wave function from $(1)$. $\Psi(r,t)$ would then describe the transition from bound to free particle. When the binding electrostatic attraction between nucleus and electron vanishes completely (when $Z(+\infty)=0$), the electron would be a free electron.

Comment: This can easily be solved exactly if we take the OP's suggestion of the nucleus instantaneously disappearing: we treat the problem as a quantum quench, where our initial state is given by the hydrogen wavefunction and the time evolution is simply given by a free particle Hamiltonian. This can then even be solved analytically (one needs to just Fourier transform the ground state of the hydrogen atom)

Comment: If one moreover wants to take into account the entanglement between the nucleus and the electron, then upon removing the nucleus the electron will be in a mixed state (with probability given by formula (25) in https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9709052 )

Comment: @RubenVerresen: why not formulate your own answer? :-)

Comment: That's  fair enough, but I do find it difficult to judge the level of the answer based on the level of the question. Anyway, your answer is far better. Its absolutely, definitely time for me to take a break from the site and learn new stuff,  I am not at all happy with my copy and paste answers. I am surprised this question is on hold though, similar "what if"  ones seemed ok. Anyway,  all the best till I come back in a few months.

Comment: *"I am surprised this question is on hold though, similar "what if" ones seemed ok."* Totally agreed. QMechanic seems a little trigger happy here. This question is not 'non-mainstream', IMHO. See u l8r.

Comment: @Gert: My comment was only intended as an add-on and not as an alternative to your answer :) As in, I was just pointing out that in the special case of $Z(t) = \theta(-t)$ the answer can be calculated analytically.

Comment: @RubenVerresen: what does $\theta(-t)$ mean?

Comment: @Gert: The heaviside function, i.e. I just mean $Z(t) = 1$ for $t\leq 0$ and $Z(t) = 0$ for $t>0$